# error with validation rule when making list of past roles

Tags: formula, validation, validation-rule

i'm working on making a list of past roles which include a start and end date from when the role was held. however i'm having trouble making it so before adding a new role, the previous role must be end dated. the end date field is not required as it could be a currently held role, but in order to make a NEW role, you must first end date the current role. so i'm making a validation rule and came up with:

```
ISNULL(End_Date__c)
```

and this runs as expected until i go to make a new rule with no end date, in which it throws the error (not expected). it only allows me to make a new role if i put an end date for it. how can i make this validation rule stop applying when i make a new role without an end date?

Comment: How are you entering the data in this list? How is this maintained today, custom object?

Comment: @JayantDas its a custom "role history" object. shows the current role, start date and end date. end date can be null if its the present role. you then add a new role (again, the end date can be null as its the new present role), but a validation error show throw only if when adding this new role, the previous role's end date is still null, telling the user to first set an end date before adding a new role. as of now it does this but requires the new role to also not be null.

Comment: With your requirement, you cannot achieve this by out of the box validation rules. You will need a trigger here so that whenever you are adding a new role record, the trigger checks if the last one has an end date already populated. If not, then throw an error.

Comment: @JayantDas any tips on writing that? i thought a before trigger would be necessary as well but struggling with the syntax...

Comment: I will recommend to take some trailhead on triggers. You’re on the right track you will need a before trigger. The logic will be that if there exists a record for the same role with no end date, you throw error when adding the new record. The User will then first need to fill in that before being able to add a new one. Honestly, I could have written this but that way you won’t be able to learn as we do here. If you are still stuck once you have made some progress, feel free to repost your issue and someone will help. All the best.